# How can i load a link in other browser from web view?

Tags: android, webview

I am loading string value in my web view and i need when i click on the link shown in web view should open in other web browser of phone.
I want like this - `String s = "hello read more.... www.google.com"
String html = "<html><body>+s+</body></html>"
webview.loaddata(html);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Comment: hey misca can you please help me. how can i open this link in other web view of other activity ?

Comment: Instead of the intent for ACTION_VIEW, make the intent to start your other activity. Use intent.putExtra to send the string url. Then get the url string from the bundle in the other activity and load it into the webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String s = "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Read more over here</a>";
webview.loaddata(s);
```

You will need to add other html content by yourself.

So basically, you can use `target='_blank'` which will open it in a new browser, not in webview.

Hope it helps.

Comment: done same as you said but still same problem it is open in same web view

Comment: @HiteshMatnani This code works fine for me. Edit question with your code. and try testing in 2-3 devices. This might be device issue.