# How can i open a link in other activity of web view?

Tags: android

How can i open a link that is displayed in web view to other activity web view?
I had load data in web view and there is a link that i need to open in other web view of other activity how can i do this ?

Comment: my web view code - web1.loadData(htmldata,"text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
          web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
              @Override
              public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                  view.loadUrl(url);
                  return false;
              }
          });

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i load a link in other browser from web view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010589/how-can-i-load-a-link-in-other-browser-from-web-view)

Comment: This code is for open the link in other web browser of phone but now i need is that the link open to other web view of other activity. Can you help me to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my case:

```
public class WebPageFragment extends Fragment {
    private String mUrl;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        mUrl = getActivity().getIntent().getData().toString();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_page, parent, false);

        /**  some settings here  **/

        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webPage_webView);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), WebPageActivity.class);
                i.setData(uri);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

        return v;
    }
}
```

The key is override the **`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`** method.
In my case I just start the same activity to load the Url.

I don't know your implementation. But try override the same method and start another instance. Pass the url by any ways and load it. I think this will work.